# Debugging rails-latex gem on Heroku | ActionView::Template::Error rails-latex failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

**Problem:**

I have a Rails app which generates a pdf via the `rails-latex` gem. It works just fine on `rails s` and `heroku local`.
However, trying to use the pdf-generation-link on Heroku throws me `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

Using `heroku logs --tail` yields me:

```
Rendered sheets/show.pdf.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode input' in /app/tmp/rails-latex/4--3678030941334020140 1 times...
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 59ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (rails-latex failed: See /app/tmp/rails-latex/4--3678030941334020140/input.log for details):
19:
20: \end{document}
app/views/layouts/application.pdf.erbtex:22:in `_app_views_layouts_application_pdf_erbtex___[LOTS OF NUMBERS]
```

Again, the rest of the Heroku app and the local version are working, so this is not a problem with models etc.

teX is installed with a buildback (the installation shows as successful when pushing). 
`heroku buildpacks` is:

```
1. heroku/ruby
2. https://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-tex.git
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to access the file referenced in the error message, however (I think because of Herokus dyno system) the `app/tmp` does not exist or isn't accessible by the `heroku run bash` console at least.

The layout file referenced in the logs contains:

```html
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,sloppy]{article}
<% @latex_config = { :recipe => [
 {:command => 'pdflatex'},
]} # you can override the defaults if you wish; see LatexToPdf#config
%>
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[a5paper, left=.3cm, right=.3cm, bottom=0cm, top=0.3cm]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

 <%= yield %>

\end{document}
```

**Conclusion:**

I'm really at a loss here because I can't get more information to debug nor replicate the error anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever stumbles upon this:

After a lot of headache I found that my file containing my tex packages (instructed in the README of the buildpack) was incorrectly named and not doing anything, so I was trying to use non-existing packages.

Fixing that sent me down another rabbithole in the world of texlive-versions, but brute-forcing my way through various version declaration and replacing libraries finally got me a working Heroku app.

If you have a similar problem, I recommend deleting all tex dependencies, get a MWE and then slowly add them back in to identify the evildoers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following debugging approach:

Generate a .tex source file in your DEV environment and upload it to the dyno (I placed the code in a Github gist and used wget in the dyno).

There you can compile it with the pdflatex command.