# rails-latex gem: ActionView::Template::Error (rails-latex failed ...) with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**Rails Version**: Rails 6.0.2.1

**Ruby Version**: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]

When I try to generate a PDF with the gem [rails-latex](https://github.com/amagical-net/rails-latex) in Heroku, I get the following error: `ActionView::Template::Error rails-latex failed` (Full error message below).

This error does not arise locally.

**What I tried**

There is already a stackoverflow-question with the same problem: [Debugging rails-latex gem on Heroku | ActionView::Template::Error rails-latex failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789173/debugging-rails-latex-gem-on-heroku-actionviewtemplateerror-rails-latex-fa)

@blackbrokkoli writes:

> If you have a similar problem, I recommend deleting all tex
>   dependencies, get a MWE and then slowly add them back in to identify
>   the evildoers.

But I don't know what he means with "MWE" and I doubt that I am able to "identify the evildoers" by myself.

---

There is a thread called "[Deploying on Heroku](https://github.com/amagical-net/rails-latex/issues/25)" suggesting that one needs to install a [buildpack](https://github.com/gulopine/heroku-buildpack-tex).

I tried to follow the instructions for the "Multipacks"-option.

The command  `cat .buildpacks` returns
`cat: .buildpacks: No such file or directory`

The command `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git` returns:

`Setting BUILDPACK_URL and restarting`

`BUILDPACK_URL: git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`

But after that, I don't know how to proceed further.

I tried to figure out how to [add buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) with Heroku with the `heroku buildpacks:add` command. But I couldn't figure out, how I can add a third-party buildpack with this command.

---

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

---

Error message in `heroku logs`

```
2020-02-07T05:50:55.909360+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.909264 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Started GET "/articles/2.pdf" for 87.245.109.31 at 2020-
02-07 05:50:55 +0000
2020-02-07T05:50:55.910207+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.910130 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Processing by ArticlesController#show as PDF
2020-02-07T05:50:55.910257+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.910202 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
2020-02-07T05:50:55.913042+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.912964 #4] DEBUG -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]   Article Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articl
es" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2020-02-07T05:50:55.914866+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.914789 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]   Rendering articles/show.pdf.erb within layouts/applica
tion

2020-02-07T05:50:55.915357+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.915290 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]   Rendered articles/show.pdf.erb within layouts/applicat
ion (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 101)
2020-02-07T05:50:55.916214+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.916141 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interact
ion=batchmode input' in /app/tmp/rails-latex/4-521112460259582216 1 times...
2020-02-07T05:50:55.923855+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.923739 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Running 'bibtex input' in /app/tmp/rails-latex/4-5211124
60259582216 1 times...
2020-02-07T05:50:55.929983+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.929846 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interact
ion=batchmode input' in /app/tmp/rails-latex/4-521112460259582216 2 times...
2020-02-07T05:50:55.936216+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.936104 #4]  INFO -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecor
d: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1610)
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937843+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-07T05:50:55.937756 #4] FATAL -- : [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937845+00:00 app[web.1]: [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] ActionView::Template::Error (rails-latex failed: See /app/tmp/rails-latex/4-521112460259582216/input.l
og for details):
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937845+00:00 app[web.1]: [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]     15:
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937846+00:00 app[web.1]: [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]     16: \end{document}
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937846+00:00 app[web.1]: [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3]
2020-02-07T05:50:55.937847+00:00 app[web.1]: [1c4e2355-293c-4cb1-b591-b97e4ba4ecf3] app/views/layouts/application.pdf.erbtex:18
```

---

@Syed Asim Hashmi suggested to use this command to install a third-party buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add git://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-tex.git#VERSION_NUMBER
```

This is what I get:

```
heroku buildpacks:add git://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-te
x.git#VERSION_NUMBER
 ›   Error: Could not find the buildpack:
 ›   git://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-tex.git#VERSION_NUMB
 ›   ER. To specify a buildpack, please format it like the following:
 ›   namespace/name (e.g. heroku/ruby). Also names can only contain
 ›   letters, numbers, '_', and '-'.
```

---

I tried to add the buildpack via the settings on the heroku website:

[image]

I restarted heroku with `heroku restart`
but I receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

`rails-latex` uses third-party buildpack

https://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-tex

You can install it by running this command:

```
heroku buildpacks:add git://github.com/Thermondo/heroku-buildpack-tex.git#VERSION_NUMBER
```

Alternatively you can also add the above git repository  into your buildpacks by going to your dyno settings.

> One thing to keep in mind is that The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral -
>   that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is
>   running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted

You can find more information regarding third party buildpacks [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-third-party-buildpack)

More information regarding heroku filesystem [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It says that it could not find the buildpack. I updated my question. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @Metaphysiker did you replace the `VERSION_NUMBER` with actual version?

Comment: If you are not sure which version to use, try removing the `#VERSION_NUMBER`

Comment: I tried without #VERSION_NUMBER, I get the same error: Error: Could not find the buildpack. Where could I find available version numbers?